# Proving a mangled graph to be connected.

Tags: graph-theory, induction, connectedness

In MIT's 6.042J course, there is a question in assignment 5 problem 3 c.

> An n-node graph is said to be mangled if there is an edge leaving every >set of n/2 or fewer vertices. Again, as a special case, the graph >consisting of a >single node is considered mangled. Prove the following >claim. Hint: Prove by contradiction.
> Claim. Every non-empty, mangled graph is connected.

I couldn't prove it by contradiction, so I attempted to prove it by induction. Is my proof correct? How can I prove it by contradiction?

> Pf (By induction on number of nodes of the graph):
>
> Base Case (P(1)): A 1-node graph is mangled and it is connected.
>
> Inductive Step, assume P(n) to prove induction hypothesis:
>
> Assuming an n-node mangled graph is connected. If we added one node to this graph, we get an n+1-node graph.
>
> Now taking this added node as a group. Since the graph is mangled, therefore this group (containing only one node) must have an edge leaving it. So, this node is connected to the former n-node graph.

Comment: Suppose your original graph was $A \to B \to C \to A$.  Any subgraph on two of the nodes would not be mangled, so we could not use your proof to show the three node graph is mangled.   I suspect that the $n/2$ may be useful

Comment: It would be mangled; because each group (subgraph) will have at least 1 edge leaving it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by contradiction.

Suppose such a graph (with $n$ vertices) is not connected. Then it has at least two components. At least one component must have at most $\frac n2$ vertices. No edge is leaving this component. Contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct. First of all, you need to know that your new graph is mangled before you can conclude that there's an edge leaving it.

Second, you're working backwards: To do an inductive proof, you'd want to start with an n+1=node mangled graph and then try to show it's connected by (1) showing there's an n-node mangled subgraph (which will be connected by the induction hypothesis) and (2) showing that the last node is connected to this subgraph.

I don't see an easy way to do this particular inductive proof, so this is just a sketch of the SHAPE of such a proof, not a claim that such a proof can be constructed.

Comment: Why do I need to show that the new graph is mangled? The graph being mangled is an assumption and I am trying to prove that it is connected. Is your proof not the same as mine, but reversing the approach in the inductive step?

Comment: You need to show the new graph is mangled because you write "Since the graph is mangled, therefore this group (containing only one node) must have an edge leaving it." Now it's not clear what "the graph" refers to , but if it refers to the original (before the node is added), then you don't know that the larger graph is mangles, so you can't conclude that there must be an edge leaving the new node -- that holds only for *mangled* graphs. If it refers to the original graph, then you can't say anything about the new node. So: in both cases, what you've written is unjustified.